# How to set variable number to inputs and format for __android_log_print

Tags: c++, printf

For example I have a vector of points only to be determined its size at runtime.

```
vector<Point2f> image_points;

....

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI","Image Points are: (%.2f,%.2f)(%.2f,%.2f)(%.2f,%.2f)(%.2f,%.2f)",
                        image_points[0].x,image_points[0].y,image_points[1].x, image_points[1].y,image_points[2].x,image_points[2].y,image_points[3].x, image_points[3].y);
```

This code I only assume that there are 4 points,but there could be anywhere from 0 to many
I think it is somehow similar to printf and vprintf but I dont understand that part neither.How do I write the va_list and formate part?And please post exact workable code in you answer.

Comment: make a function which makes string representation from `vector<Point2f>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you **could** construct a dynamic format string and concoct a `va_list` to match, you might as well skip that and generate the final output locally and just ship a string to the Android logger.

Using `std::string` as a buffer for convenience:

```cpp
std::string buf;
buf.reserve(image_points.size() * 32);
char tmp[32];
for (const auto & point: image_points) {
  sprintf(tmp, "(%.2f, %.2f)", point.x, point.y);
  buf.append(tmp);
}
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI","Image Points are: %s", buf.c_str());
```

Comment: hmm...this looks like might just suit the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I summarized so I customised a to_string function to convert vector< Point2f > to std::string

```
vector<Point2f> image_points;
template<typename T>
String to_string(vector<Point_<T>> input){
    if (std::is_same<T, float>::value) {
        std::string buf;
        buf.reserve(input.size() * 32);
        char tmp[32];
        for (const auto &point: input) {
            sprintf(tmp, "(%.2f, %.2f)", point.x, point.y);
            buf.append(tmp);
        }
        return buf;
    }

....//some code in between

 __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "JNI","Image Points are: 
 %s",to_string(image_points).c_str());
```

Anyone have other suggestion any way to write even more simpler function please feel free to comment

Comment: Make sure you take `input` as a const reference instead of by copy!